# Openstack installation error with nova and authentification

Tags: linux, puppet, openstack

This is the first time i'm using openstack, I'm really a new one, I'm doing right now an OpenStack packstack installation, I've generated an answer file in which i specify the following parameters : (notice that I've followed a website doing that i don't know exactly what does all of these parameters means)

```
      CONFIG_PROVISION_DEMO=n
  CONFIG_NEUTRON_ML2_TYPE_DRIVERS=flat,vxlan 
  CONFIG_NEUTRON_ML2_TENANT_NETWORK_TYPES=vxlan 
  CONFIG_NEUTRON_ML2_MECHANISM_DRIVERS=openvswitch 
  CONFIG_NEUTRON_L2_AGENT=openvswitch 
  CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVS_EXTERNAL_PHYSNET=extnet 
  CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVS_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS=extnet:br-ex 
  CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVS_BRIDGE_IFACES=br-ex:em1
```

I'm getting the following error :
**ERROR : Error appeared during Puppet run: 10.53.193.172_controller.pp Notice: /Stage[main]/Nova::Db::Sync/Exec[nova-db-sync]/returns: Error: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, u"Access denied for user 'nova'@'10.53.193.172' (using password: YES)") (Background on this error at: sqlalche.me/e/e3q8) You will find full trace in log /var/tmp/packstack/20210401-074033-eKhyZ8/manifests/10.53.193.172_controller.pp.log**

I've search how to solve it,and i didn't find anything helpful, so i ignored it and I've try to re-run the **packstack --answer-file=answerfile.txt**, and I'm getting this time a new error :
**ERROR : Error appeared during Puppet run: 10.53.193.172_controller.pp
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not authenticate**
**You will find full trace in log /var/tmp/packstack/20210401-082518-KWFGCT/manifests/10.53.193.172_controller.pp.log
Please check log file /var/tmp/packstack/20210401-082518-KWFGCT/openstack-setup.log for more information**

Any help, please !

Comment: From where did you get this answer file? Did you launch the `packstack` command on a fresh Centos/RHEL installation? If not, reinstall the operating system to ensure nothing is left from an earlier Packstack, and try again. Ensure that your machine's NIC is named `em1`, or adapt the name in the answer file.

Comment: @berndbausch i generate the answer file with the command : packstack --gen-answer-file=answerfile.txt , then i did a vi answerfile.txt and modify some parameters, concerning the OS, yes i have a fresh installation of it !

Comment: I meant from where you have the modification of the answer file. However I don't think the answer file causes the problem. My suspicion was that the database existed already when you set up the Packstack cloud, but if you ran the `packstack` command on a fresh OS, that can't be the case. Which version of Centos and OpenStack is that?

Comment: By the way, when you ran `packstack` the second time, your OS was not freshly installed. You ran `packstack` on a system that had a partially installed Packstack, which is likely to fail.

Comment: @berndbausch i am using centos 7.9 2009 release, i've deleted the openstack release by doing : yum remove centos-release-openstack-train and i'm going to install it back again.....

Comment: If the same old database is still installed, it's no wonder you run into problems. You need to remove the database at least, but I don't know if there is anything else left over that causes trouble. That's why I recommend reinstalling the operating system.